# search a json object using a property and fetch all the corresponding properties of the object

Tags: javascript, json, search

I have a json array with objects having a property product ID. I'm able to fetch productids and store it in an array and populate  the search box with product ids. Now on selecting a product id from the search box, corresponding latitude and longitude properties of that object needs to be stored in an array. Can any one suggest a way to do this? Below is my code to fetch json data and populate the search box with product ids.

```
function loadsearch(){

     $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: 'data.json',
        dataType: "json",
        crossDomain: true,
        success: function parse(response){
 for(k=0;k<response.BMS.length;k++){
productids.push(response.BMS[k].prodid)
     // var ci = response.records[i].city;

 }

        }
});
}
loadsearch();
$(function()
                {
                    $( "#searchbox" ).autocomplete({
                        source: productids,
                        select: function(event,ui){
                            var va = ui.item.value;
                           // hos(va);
                            //searchVal(va);
                        }
                    });
                });
```

Below is my json:

```
{
    "BMS": [{
        "type": "point",
        "prodid": "NA",
        "fname": "VID_20160907_175716991.mp4",
        "coordinates": "[18.49536685 , 73.81291993]",
        "lat": "18.49536685",
        "lng": "73.81291993",
        "date": "2016-09-07",
        "time": "now",
        "status": "rescan"
    }, {
        "type": "point",
        "prodid": "NA",
        "fname": "VID_20160908_102145088.mp4",
        "coordinates": "[18.49532624 , 73.81284719]",
        "lat": "18.49532624",
        "lng": "73.81284719",
        "date": "2016-09-08",
        "time": "now",
        "status": "rescan"
    }, {
        "type": "point",
        "prodid": "NA",
        "fname": "VID_20160909_103928123.mp4",
        "coordinates": "[18.49547267 , 73.81294396]",
        "lat": "18.49547267",
        "lng": "73.81294396",
        "date": "2016-09-09",
        "time": "now",
        "status": "rescan"
    }, {
        "type": "point",
        "prodid": "01234567",
        "fname": "VID_20160909_104658010.mp4",
        "coordinates": "[18.49541044 , 73.81292334]",
        "lat": "18.49541044",
        "lng": "73.81292334",
        "date": "2016-09-09",
        "time": "now",
        "status": "authentic"
    }, {
        "type": "point",
        "prodid": "NA",
        "fname": "VID_20160909_104958231.mp4",
        "coordinates": "[18.49538404 , 73.81292148]",
        "lat": "18.49538404",
        "lng": "73.81292148",
        "date": "2016-09-09",
        "time": "now",
        "status": "rescan"
    }, {
        "type": "point",
        "prodid": "01234567",
        "fname": "VID_20160909_105249111.mp4",
        "coordinates": "[18.49538324 , 73.81292229]",
        "lat": "18.49538324",
        "lng": "73.81292229",
        "date": "2016-09-09",
        "time": "now",
        "status": "authentic"
    }, {
        "type": "point",
        "prodid": "NA",
        "fname": "VID_20160909_115447094.mp4",
        "coordinates": "[18.58629075 , 73.821569]",
        "lat": "18.58629075",
        "lng": "73.821569",
        "date": "2016-09-09",
        "time": "now",
        "status": "rescan"
    }, {
        "type": "point",
        "prodid": "NA",
        "fname": "VID_20160909_120629821.mp4",
        "coordinates": "[18.58629075 , 73.821569]",
        "lat": "18.58629075",
        "lng": "73.821569",
        "date": "2016-09-09",
        "time": "now",
        "status": "rescan"
    }, {
        "type": "point",
        "prodid": "NA",
        "fname": "VID_20160909_121752248.mp4",
        "coordinates": "[18.58629075 , 73.821569]",
        "lat": "18.58629075",
        "lng": "73.821569",
        "date": "2016-09-09",
        "time": "now",
        "status": "rescan"
    }, {
        "type": "point",
        "prodid": "01234567",
        "fname": "VID_20160909_124615416.mp4",
        "coordinates": "[18.49540612 , 73.8129407]",
        "lat": "18.49540612",
        "lng": "73.8129407",
        "date": "2016-09-09",
        "time": "now",
        "status": "authentic"
    }, {
        "type": "point",
        "prodid": "NA",
        "fname": "VID_20160909_140442837.mp4",
        "coordinates": "[18.58629075 , 73.821569]",
        "lat": "18.58629075",
        "lng": "73.821569",
        "date": "2016-09-09",
        "time": "now",
        "status": "rescan"
    }, {
        "type": "point",
        "prodid": "01234567",
        "fname": "VID_20160913_175112167.mp4",
        "coordinates": "[18.58384342 , 73.82221776]",
        "lat": "18.58384342",
        "lng": "73.82221776",
        "date": "2016-09-13",
        "time": "now",
        "status": "authentic"
    }, {
        "type": "point",
        "prodid": "01234567",
        "fname": "VID_20160913_175131116.mp4",
        "coordinates": "[18.4954413 , 73.8129359]",
        "lat": "18.4954413",
        "lng": "73.8129359",
        "date": "2016-09-13",
        "time": "now",
        "status": "authentic"
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for the function map of array. Here is an example:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'data.json',
    dataType: "json",
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function parse(response){
    productids = response.BMS.map(
        function (p) {
            return p.prodid 
        }
    );
}
```

**EDIT**

Example:

```
var a = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var b = a.map( function (x) { return x*2; } );
console.log(b); //it shows [2,4,6,8]
```

For more information here are more details:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: Thank you for your help. But could you please bit explain me how map works?

Comment: Of course! You send the function another function as parameter. This function must receive 1 parameter and return the value you want to store.

For example:

var a = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var b = a.map( function (x) { return x*2; } );
console.log(b); //it shows [2,4,6,8]